# How to nest WHERE plus AND conditions with laravel query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need something like this:

```
public function myFunc(Request $request) {
    $search = $request->input('searchString');
    $myOjb = myModel::where('field1', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
                    ->orwhere('field2', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
                    ->orwhere('field3', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
                    ->orwhere('field4', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
                    ->where('field5','yes')

}
```

I need to bring data where any of those `like` are true AND field `field5 = yes` is a MUST BE.

The problem is: It brings me data even if `field5` is not found.
How to filter it correctly?

Didn't understand enough: [Advanced Wheres](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below by passing a closure on where()

```
myModel::where('field5', 'YES')->where(function ($q) use($search) {
                                                     ^^^
    return $q->where('field1', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
              ->orwhere('field2', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
              ->orwhere('field3', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
              ->orwhere('field4', 'like', '%' .$search . '%');
});
```

EDIT
You  need to pass the variable to closure using `use`

Comment: Thanks ! Are you sure this is right ? It found `an unexpected '}' should be ';'` at the end

Comment: It's missing a semicolon at the end of the last `orWhere()`.

Comment: sorry for typo :)

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question: It says `Undefined variable search`

Comment: After resolving bugs I made. Everything worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
$myOjb = myModel::where('field1', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
                ->where('field5','yes')
                ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('field2', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
                      ->orWhere('field3', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
                      ->orWhere('field4', 'like', '%' .$search . '%');
                });
```

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question: It says `Undefined variable search`

Comment: Check `search variable`scope. whether it is available in the function or not.